# Divs not lining up in Bootstrap/Javascript checkbox menu

Tags: javascript

I made this checkbox menu. I want all divs to line up under and around each other when each box is checked, which some do beautifully, using Bootstrap. However, when you check "Research Methods," the two divs are separated from eachother and don't line up at the top/next to each other. I am wondering why this is? Here is a live demo:

http://dev.wwnorton.com/sandbox/showcase2015/test/OEBPS5/1-ChooseANorton.html

Here is the code:

```
Javascript:

$('#chkIntroPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvIntroPsych').show():$('#dvIntroPsych').hide();
});

$('#chkIntroPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvIntroPsych1').show():$('#dvIntroPsych1').hide();
});

$('#chkIntroPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvIntroPsych2').show():$('#dvIntroPsych2').hide();
});

$('#chkResearch').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvResearch').show():$('#dvResearch').hide();
});

$('#chkResearch').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvResearch2').show():$('#dvResearch2').hide();
});

$('#chkSocPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvSocPsych').show():$('#dvSocPsych').hide();
});

$('#chkSocPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvSocPsych2').show():$('#dvSocPsych2').hide();
});

$('#chkSocPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvSocPsych3').show():$('#dvSocPsych3').hide();
});

$('#chkCogPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvCogPsych').show():$('#dvCogPsych').hide();
});

$('#chkCogPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvCogPsych2').show():$('#dvCogPsych2').hide();
});

$('#chkPersonPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvPersonPsych').show():$('#dvPersonPsych').hide();
});

$('#chkPersonPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvPersonPsych2').show():$('#dvPersonPsych2').hide();
});

$('#chkDevPsych').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvDevPsych').show():$('#dvDevPsych').hide();
});

$('#chkHistory').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#dvHistory').show():$('#dvHistory').hide();
});

});

And CSS:

.spacer {
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
}

.bookcontainer {
width: 100%;
float: left;
display: block;
min-height: 260px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 20px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #acacac;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #acacac;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #acacac;
border-radius:5px;
vertical-align: top;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.bookcontainer .book img {
border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
width: 20%;
height: 20%;
float: left;
margin-right: 15px;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
} 

.maintoc {
width:100%;
clear: both;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.maintoc a {
text-decoration: none;
}

label {
text-align:center; 
line-height:18px;
font-family:Lato;
font-weight:bold;
color:#0092c8;
font-size:15px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
background: white;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
box-sizing: content-box ;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border-width: 0;
position: relative;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: -5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
  background-color: #0092c8;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus{
  outline: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.ckbatch {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
margin: 10px;
}

.ckbatchcontainer {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 0;
}

.TOCtext {
text-align:center; 
line-height:18px;
font-family:Lato;
font-weight:bold;
color:#948973;
font-size:15px;
}

.TOCtext a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.TOCimage {
height: 150px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
display: block;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any and all help! I've been wracking my brain for a week and in forums to try and fix this simple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer in a well explaining way probably bust this comment, therefore I'll provide only a working solution for your problem. So just add these lines of Javascript:

```
$('.ckbatchcontainer [type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('id').replace(/chk/, '[id^=dv') + ']';
  var target = $(id).parent();
  target.siblings(':not([style])').hide();
  this.checked ? target.show() : target.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Nemoinho. I added that Javascript, but it sadly didn't fix it :(

Comment: Sadly that additional css didn't work either, it made some divs disappear in the Choose your Norton for your Psychology Course section and all disappear in the Choose Your Norton section :(

Comment: Pardon I was a little bit too fast with my answer and didn't take a deep look into your code, but I updated it now with some lines which I actually tested.

Comment: Nemoinho, this is a miracle, thank you! It works beautifully. Is it possible to explain why this was occurring, or point me toward a resource that explains it so I can understand? Do you think the CSS checkbox hack is better for this sort of function in the future? Thanks!